# What aircraft (real or fictional) does this look most like?

Tags: aircraft-identification, flying-wing

I just finished building a foam board plane. I did not follow any plans and this is just me being stupid and making a plane that I hope will fly. pic below.

[image: foam board plane]

Its a flying wing with a bit of dihedral, vertical stabilizers on either end, small elevators, and a rudder. I have not yet flown it due to bad batteries, so I don't actually know if it flies yet.

What real or fictional aircraft does this look most like?

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as opinon-based, as the aircraft-identification tag is to match photos/models of real aircraft to their "sources". As this lacks a source, I don't see how the answer would not be matter of opinion.

Comment: @Ceramcmrno0b Is the aerofoil cambered or symmetrical? If it is cambered, i.e. with more of a hump across the top than underneath, then it will need a much larger elevator trimmed to a significant "up" angle at the rear, and the CG moved forward to match, to fly stably.

Comment: It looks just like the fictional one in my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it comes closest to the [Backstrom EB-1 Flying Plank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backstrom_EPB-1_Flying_Plank), a tailless glider designed in the 50s.  The rear control surfaces are doing the job of the horizontal tail for pitch control and you will need some UP deflection at their "neutral" position to get it to not dive straight into the ground as soon as it's on its own in flight.  Then you have to find the right spot for the C of G.

Being very short coupled, you will find that the C of G range in which it will fly, if it will at all, is very small and it will take some experimentation to find a CG location where it is stable and controllable at the same time, and you should probably do tests by just throwing it into glide before trying to fly it with the motor.

In the RC world, all kinds of weird configurations and shapes will work that won't with full size airplanes (like flying lawnmowers) so it should be possible to get it to fly ok with lots of tweaking.  Check [this](https://www.mh-aerotools.de/airfoils/flywing1.htm) page out for some tips on designing flying wing model aircraft.